# efficient way to do bulk updates where values are assigned serially from a list?

Tags: grails, hql

Lets say there is a domain A with property p.

```
class A{
 Integer p
}
```

I have a list of A i.e

```
def lis = A.list()
```

and then i have a list of numbers

```
def num = [4, 1, 22, ......]
```

what is the most efficient way to do bulk update in grails where each object of A is assigned a number from num serially.

One way could be

```
for(int i=0; i<lis.size(); i++){
  lis[i].p = num[i]
  lis[i].save(flush: true)
}
```

But this solution i assume is not efficient. Can this be achieved using HQL or other efficient methods? I appreciate any help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I agree that your solution is likely to be inefficient, it's mostly due to the fact that you're flushing on every save. So you can get a performance boost by using a [transaction](http://gorm.grails.org/6.0.x/hibernate/manual/#programmaticTransactions); which automatically causes a flush when committed:

```
A.withTransaction { status ->
    ...

    for(int i=0; i<lis.size(); i++) {
        lis[i].p = num[i]
        lis[i].save()
    }
}
```

Of course, if you can use the @[Transactional](http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/single.html#declarativeTransactions) annotation, that would be better.

Yes, you can use HQL, but the fundamental problem here is that your list of numbers is arbitrary, so you'd need multiple HQL queries; one for each update.

Try the transactional approach first, since that's the easiest to set up.

Answer (score 1):

if your list of A and numbers is a very great amount of data to treat (if lis.size is for example equal to 10 000), then you should do this :

```
  A.withNewTransaction { status -> // begin a new hibernate session

    int stepForFlush = 100
    int totalLisSize = A.count()
    def lis

    for(int k=0; k < totalLisSize; k+=stepForFlush) {

      lis = A.list(max: stepForFlush, offset: k) // load only 100 elements in the current hibernate session
      ...

      for(int i=0; i<lis.size(); i++) {
        lis[i].p = num[k+i]
        lis[i].save()
      }
      A.withSession { session ->
        session.flush() // flush changes to database
        session.clear() // clear the hibernate session, the 100 elements are no more attached to the hibernate session
                        // Then they are now eligible to garbage collection
                        // you ensure not maintaining in memory all the elements you are treating
      }
    } // next iteration, k+=100


  } // Transaction is closed then transaction is commited = a commit is executed to database,
    // and then all changes that has been flush previously are committed.
```

Note :

In this solution, you do not load all your A elements in memory and it helps when your A.list().size() is very great.